# Android facebook Library Issue

Tags: android, facebook

I added these imports in beginning of my project activity

```
import com.facebook.android.*;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
```

And in menifest file i added these

`**<uses-library  android:name="com.facebook.android"/>**` inside `</apllication>` tag

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` outside `</application>` tag

All reference to facebook sdk has been done.still it is showing problems with the above imports because it is not recognising them.Any one any idea!!!!

Comment: Hm, should it be in your <uses-lib.. "com.facebook.android" instead of  "com.android.facebook" ?

Comment: No buddy it does not work. :(

Comment: Did u do as said in the android-facebook sdk tutorial? u created new project and marked as library? then in ur project added the newly created project  as reference?

Comment: I created a project using face-book-sdk using create project from exisiting resource as said in tutorial.But i dont know how to mark it as library, but i created another new project and give reference to it.

Comment: @AndroidKiller project-->properties--> check Is Library box

Comment: I did that but still it is not working. :(

Comment: It is not recognising the imports at all as i said in my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having compilation problem then clean and build again...

If not so...
then try this

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

Just try this  it is working with no errors..

Thanks...hope it is helpful....

[[image]android](/questions/tagged/android)[facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook)

Comment: Thanks buddy i follow this link only.Everything is ok.But problem my project is not recognising the imports.And i have also tried with cleaning and building project.Any other idea ?

Comment: I think you lost resources for build.May be changing target android version will fix that.If not so then it is better to create new project n copy your code.

Comment: I am using android 2.3.3.Any problem with this ?

Comment: Not at all.Sometime i faced this kind of problem n after many try i failed to get reason behind this.will tell you if i'll get reason.but right now you should adopt this whether it is legal or not.